# How to call a function before $.post() callback displays alert()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blockui

I'll note that this code is not something I built, I'm simply making some UI changes using a plugin on a system that's already in place.

I'm building a plugin that's utilizing [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) (yes, I need to build a plugin with a plugin) in order to display a loading icon over certain elements when an Ajax call is fired, however this one in particular calls an `alert()` if the `success()` event doesn't get the response it needs.

The result of this is my loading icon calling `fadeOut()` *after* the `alert` fires, which is not what I want it to do.

When I call the function I'm building, I pass in `$.post()` complete with the settings and options I need, like this:

```
$.fn.startLoading({            
    element: $("div"),
    ajax: $.post('some.url',
    {
        //Ajax settings...
    }, function (response) {   //This is the success function, right?
            if (good) {
                //stuff
            }
            else
                alert("Bad!"); //This happens BEFORE fadeOut()
        }
    }, 'text')
    .error(function (msg) {
        alert('Worse error!');
    })
});
```

My plugin's function takes all of this in as one `options` parameter, like so:

`$.fn.startLoading = function (options) { ...`

I then access the `$.post()` call like this:

```
if (options.ajax)
    ajax = options.ajax;
```

This is where I'm stuck. I need to make sure that the `fadeOut()` happens before the `success` event is fired. How can I do this using the `ajax` variable I've created in my plugin?

Comment: Syntax error here: `ajax: $.post('some.url'),{` should probably remove `)`

Comment: Also, `jqXHR.error` is depreciated, you should use .fail instead.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you are trying to do since you have no control over when the ajax request is sent from inside the plugin. You would either need to delay sending the ajax request, or not perform anything inside the success until the fadeout is complete, both of which are somewhat out of context.

Comment: I would modify the plugin to instead accept a function that performs the ajax request so that the plugin can decide when to send the ajax request, or, have the plugin accept ajax options that you then modify inside the plugin, and again having control over when it is sent.

Comment: Right, but since you have no control over the order that the success callbacks get added, and you have no control over when the request is sent, there's no way for you to delay the success from happening unless you do it directly inside the success callback.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer and accept it; do not edit your question with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is with ajaxComplete, ajaxSuccess etc http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Those are global ajax handlers that grab ALL ajax requests sent via jQuery... so you could set a handler in there and whitelist your own callback elements etc so that you ignore ones that are not of your concern.

In my testing these global handlers fire BEFORE the handlers of the specific ajax call.